# Why is it not OK to call Matplotlib from Sublime Text 2?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, sublimetext2, spyder

My Matplotlib was installed as part of the [Spyder](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) DMG package. Now, I am trying to write Python code with Sublime Text 2. But my code, which uses the `figure()` method and `from pylab import *` statement, cannot load Matplotlib. The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xx/Desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pylab import *
ImportError: No module named pylab
[Finished in 1.3s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Just run `sudo pip install matplotlib` from the command line and you should be all set. If you use a package manager like MacPorts then `sudo port install pyXX-matplotlib` is the way to go, especially if you're using Python 3.

Comment: @nordev I guess I was installing the Matplotlib by Macports. Sorry for that I forget that because it's long time ago...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) I haven't used Sublime but it seems you have to do these things:

1. Install [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL)
2. Configure it to use the Python interpreter that comes with our DMG, which has `matplotlib` and also `IPython`, `scikit-learn`, `scikit-image`, `scipy`, `sympy` and `pandas`. It's full path can be found in:

   `Spyder > Preferences > Console > Advanced Settings > Python Executable`

*Note*: I also recommend you to install a Python scientific distribution, which comes with a much larger amount of scientific packages. My preferred one is [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `matplotlib` before you can import anything from `pylab`. Try installing the package from the [downloads page](http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html). (exactly as @nordev says)

Comment: I guess I installed the Matplotlib from Macports. What can I do now? Thanks!